# issue while freezing li tag in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, css, jquery-mobile

I dynamically created list view using Ajax and json with jQuery mobile everything works fine except 1 condition. i have to freeze 1st Li tag in list view to show as header. i tried data-position="fixed" but it's not working for Li tag. any other way to freeze 1st Li in list view??

example

[image]

here is my code.

```
function popupFunc(data, status) {

            var no = JSON.parse(data.d);


            // creating html string
            var PoplistCode = '<ul data-role="listview"  data-inset="true" data-theme="d"  id="customerList">' + '<li id="header" data-role="list-divider" data-position="fixed" data-inset="true" data-theme="a" >Code: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Name:</li>';

            // running a loop
            $.each(no, function (index, value) {
                PoplistCode += '<li><a href="home.aspx?Batch=' + this.dept + '">'  + this.id + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'  + this.id + '</a></li>';

            });

             PoplistCode += '</ul>';
//            //appending to the div
             $('#Popvalue').html(PoplistCode);

             $('#Popvalue').addClass("popheight");



//            // refreshing the list to apply styles
             $("#Popvalue").trigger("create");

             $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();

        }
```

i dynamically creating li tags from json object. i need to freeze 1st li which is contain id as **header**.

Comment: Can't you keep the header in separate tag `<h1></h1>` instead `li`?

Comment: @TheReader i dynamically generating more <li> tag in that 1st li should be fixed. using h1 tag will spoil my listview structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

change your first li element to this ==> `<li data-role="list-divider">Menu</li>`

**working example [HERE - FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9M935/)**

**UPDATE FIDDLE:**

[FIDDLE-DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/k9hSB/1/)

what you have to do is to update your javascript with the id and class and add the style in your .css file

let me know if this is what you looking for

Comment: @user22332273: sry its not working. the 1st li tag is not fixed. it scrolling wit other li.

Comment: what you try to do?  fixed the first element? and only scroll the others? give me some code to see what you got

Comment: @user22332273: i updated post. plz see it. i need to freeze id="header" li tag alone.

Comment: @User22332273: when more li tag is added then the header is li not freezable in ur fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/Rajthilak/k9hSB/. plz guide me

Comment: i think i dont understand what you mean with freezable. what you want to do with this header? not clickable? fixed the position and scroll the content of the view?  explain pls to understand

Comment: fixed the position and scroll the content of the view.. this is i need.

Comment: i need to fix the position of 1st li and scroll the remaing content.. can i do it. it my 1st jqm app and i stuck in this from morning.